# Verification for this proof

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, proof-verification

Sorry guys about the verification questions but it's near the end of the semester and I am very sheepish about making mistakes especially because real analysis is a very important course it's only the underlying theory of calculus.

This problem may seem rudimentary but we were given a sample test by our professor and it is worth quite a bit of marks I need to make sure I'm not wrong.

-----END EXPLANATION------

Here's the problem:

Prove: Prove $(1+x)^n ≥ 1+nx$. Where $x>-1$ and $n≥2$.

My Proof:

First we'll start off with the fact,

$(1+x)^2≥2x+1$ when $x>-1$ which is equivalent to $x^2>0$ which is obviously true for a real $x$.

So, by induction, we must prove if,

$(1+x)^n≥1+nx$

Than,

$(1+x)^{n+1}≥1+(n+1)x$.

Here's my proof:

$(x+1)^n(x+1)≥(1+x)+nx$

Therefore,

$(x+1)^n≥1+\frac{nx}{x+1}$.

If, $(x+1)^n≥1+nx$ then surely,

$(x+1)^n ≥ 1+\frac{nx}{x+1}$

Q.E.D

Any help or other method will be appreciated.

Comment: I think the basis step is for $n=2$ and not $n=0$.

Comment: Actually, the base step can be $n=0$ (you can check it by yourself).

Comment: Always start with the question. Apologize later, of you need to apologize. Answerers don't come here to read about your life, however exciting  it is. If you want to be considerate, make it easier for readers to help you by creating a clear title and don't make them read irrelevant details to find out the question.

Comment: It is "then" not "than". Spelling is important too!

Comment: @user21820 I know this it was another careless error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have: $(1+x)^{n+1} = (1+x)^n(1+x) \geq (1+nx)(1+x) = 1+nx+x+nx^2\geq 1+nx+x = 1+(1+n)x$

Comment: Is my answer still right though?

Comment: Your proof is plainly wrong.

Comment: where did I go wrong?

Comment: @Aleksandar: Exactly in the way I mentioned in my answer... It is a common logical fallacy.

Answer (score 3):

The reasoning you are using for your proof can be distilled to the following:

> I want to prove that if a triangle has all angles equal, then its angles are all $60^\circ$. Here is my proof. Its angles are all $60^\circ$. Therefore its angles are surely all equal.

I hope it is clear why this reasoning is invalid.

One more thing. "Q.E.D." is quite useless.